# На каком языке и инструменте писать тесты для сайтов?

Tags: юнит-тесты, selenium, selenium-webdriver, тестирование

Необходимо писать для сайтов определенные тесты, включающие взаимодействие со страницей (нажатие на кнопку, проверка на существование элемента, проверка текста внутри элемента, скролл страницы), делать это всё надо последовательно и с определенными интервалами.

Начал с Selenium webdriver + node.js, две недели мучаюсь с ним. Поиск и проверка элементов ужасно сложная, код становится громоздким всего за пару действий.

Читал, что используют тот же Selenium но с Java и это вроде как лучше, так ли это?

Какой вообще инструментарий использовать посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Поиск и проверка элементов ужасно сложная

Советую начать с изучения локаторов страницы, если нету времени - используй для поиска элементов Selenium Builder(расширение для FireFox).

Если есть возможность, договоритесь с разработчиками о присвоение ID уникальным элементам и используйте их в качестве локаторов. Если ID не возможен, то альтернатива CSS локаторы или XPath ([Подробнее CSS локаторы и XPath](https://kreisfahrer.gitbooks.io/selenium-webdriver/content/webdriver_api_slozhnie_vzaimodeistviya/lokatori_css,_xpath,_jquery.html)).

> код становится громоздким всего за пару действий.

Решение - page object pattern. А лучше используй Selenium + Python + PyTest + ООП, тесты получаются максимально читабельные.

Comment: А почему не искать нормально по By.cssSelector?

Comment: @sinneren К чему твой вопрос не понимаю, я ответил, дал 2 варианта поиска локаторов:


1) Изучить хорошенько локаторы и самостоятельно искать
2) Использовать Selenium Builder (кликать на элементы и получать By.cssSelector )